# Javascript: Cannot assign to read only property '_epoch' of false

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

I have a method to process the response from my google javascript client (gapi):

```
var processResponse = function(response) {
              result._state = 'loaded';
              response._epoch = (new Date()).getTime();
              ...
```

A few times I have gotten the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_epoch' of false
    at processResponse (http://0.0.0.0:9000/scripts/services/haparaapi.js:110:31)
    at wrappedCallback (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js:20892:81)
    at http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js:20978:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js:21967:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js:21796:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js:22071:24)
    at http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-gapi/modules/gapi-client.js:121:32
    at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.hE_reuZ6VdE.…/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCPj66Crj6soG8dKJE8lBSc_RPXXKA/cb=gapi.loaded_0:604:138
    at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.hE_reuZ6VdE.…/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCPj66Crj6soG8dKJE8lBSc_RPXXKA/cb=gapi.loaded_0:579:311
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.hE_reuZ6VdE.…1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCPj66Crj6soG8dKJE8lBSc_RPXXKA/cb=gapi.loaded_0:163:76)
```

This bug doesn't usually happen so I haven't managed to log what the response actually looked like.

What does the error mean? Should I not be assigning values to the response?

Comment: It means what it says... `_epoch` is a *read-only* property, therefore you *cannot* assign any value to it...

Comment: Thanks - What's a read-only property? I didn't know javascript had them. I suppose the gapi must be using them to make sure their variables don't get clobbered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2428505/632088 - mentions object.seal & object.freeze - could that be the cause?

Comment: I tried playing around with the methods here: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/
but wasn't able to cause an error on a readonly property. I was using strict mode too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that your `processResponse()` callback is actually being given a value of `false`. So essentially you are trying to assign the _epoch property of a false value.

See:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientRequest

From the manual:

> The callback function which executes when the request succeeds or fails. jsonResp contains the response parsed as JSON. If the response is not JSON, **this field will be false**.

When you're running javascript in strict mode (`'use strict'`), it will raise a `TypeError` like you are experiencing:

```
'use strict';
var processResponse = function(response) {
    response._epoch = (new Date()).getTime();
};

processResponse(false);   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_epoch' of false
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0tq6mobm/

Suggest that you check the value of response before trying to assign your timestamp to the `response`.

Comment: awesome thanks! I wasn't using strict mode correctly when I tested assigning _epoch to false. Cheers. Also I think the response wasn't JSON because my endpoints hadn't finished deploying to app engine before I set the new version as the default version

Comment: I got a very similar error when a REST API unexpectedly returned a blank string rather than the expected JSON object - and code like `result.someProperty = "blah"` thus raised this error.