# Create variables that can be accessed globally but can not be modified in the developer console

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures, global-variables

How to create variables that can be accessed globally but can be modified only by a certain function?

Comment: you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

Now with ecma 6 you can declare global variable with the keyword const, and these variables won't be modified.

```
const VARIABLE="wont be modified";
```

Moreover every time you create a function a closure is created.
A closure is an inner function that has access to the outer function's variables, so you can create a function and work with it's closure

```js
 (function(global){
        var a="I'm a";
        function modifyA(newvalue){
           a=newvalue;
        }
        function getA(){
           return a;
        } 
        global.modifyA=modifyA;
        global.getA=getA;      
    })(window);

console.log(typeof a,"a doesn't exist in global environment");
console.log(getA(),"but exist in getA's closure");
modifyA('I have a new value');
console.log(getA(),"A can only be modify it with modifyA function");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish something similar is to create a local function that would set the value and create a new 'get' function to return the value like:

```
function createObjectGetter(obj)
{
    this.getObject = function() { return obj; };
}
```

Then when you call it like `createObjectGetter("abc")`, from that point you can fetch the object like `getObject()` which will return `"abc"` while the value stays constant and is only adjustable through `createObjectGetter()` method.

Here's a reference: [How can you make a variable/Object read only in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428409/how-can-you-make-a-variable-object-read-only-in-javascript)