#  is an instance of a javascript function object immutable

Tags: javascript, web-services, security

am I right to say that an instance of a function object is immutable since there's no way we could modify a function once its created?

Anyway, to rephrase my question:

```
  var f1=function(){
        return true;
    }

    //Now i pass **f1** into the function **G**, storing it to **g1**
    function G(f){
    return function(){
            return f();
    }
    }
    var g1=G(f1);

    //I will try to hack/do anything i can to **f1**
    //Now i will pass f1 to hacked piece of injection code which (assumingly) will try to hack f1


    g1(); // but I can be 100% sure this will still return me true
```

So now can I be sure that no matter what I do to **f1**, **g1()** will Forever return me **true** ?

Despite being interested in browsers with at least 0.5% of the internet users market share: I welcome answers that goes along the lines of "in [x] browser this is not safe because.."

I am aware that since the code is run at the client, if the client has a malicious intent he will be able to do whatever he want.. But this question is specifically targeted at protecting "users who do not have malicious intents", in other words.. a normal user (if the user is a hacker than i don't mind letting him mess with the functions anyway he wants since he'd get all the exceptions thrown in his face and that's none of my business)

Comment: Do you mean the function *body* or the object's *properties*?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler I've edited the question

Comment: Your code will error when calling `g1()` because `g1` is `true`. I think you meant to make the body of `G` be `return f;`. Either way, all you are doing is passing `f1` around, so, in this case, any changes to it will be reflected wherever it is. However, I don't think there's a legit way to change the function body after the function has been declared. It also depends on if you function references anything outside it.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler nop, the function does not reference to anything outside. So basically we can be 100% sure the function body cannot be touched?

Comment: @Pacerier: The only way I know of is to completely swap out the function body with a new function. And since `g1` now contains a reference to the function in `f1`, swapping out the body of `f1` doesn't really matter. That's all I can say right now, I am certainly not qualified enough to say that I am 100% certain that nothing else can happen. And I don't want to be liable :-P

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler dang there was a serious typo mistake in the code previously which i've not noticed.. pls read the question agian thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop the variable `g1` from being reassigned on all browsers.  Some browsers would allow you to define `g1` as a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) thus:

```
const g1 = G(f1);
```

which would prevent the name `g1` from being rebound, and you can use `Object.defineProperty` to define a [read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript) global property of `window` on others, but in general, there are no `const` definitions in JavaScript.

To make it clearer, consider two scenarios:

(1) An attacker can run code in the scope in which `f1` is declared, and then other code reads `f1`.

```
var f1 = ...;   // You define f1
f1 = function () { return false; };  // Attacker code runs
doSomethingWith(f1());  // Naive code reads f1 and calls it.
```

The attacker succeeds in this case in confusing the naive code because they changed the value at `f1`.

(2) An attacker runs code in the scope after `f1` has been read.

```
var f1 = ...;  // You define f1
// Cautious code reads and stores f1 in a safe place for later use.
(function () {
  var f = f1;
  setTimeout(0, function () { doSomethingWith(f()); });
})();
f1 = function () { return false; };  // Attacker code runs.
```

The attacker fails in this case because the cautious code read the value of `f1` before the attacker changed the value stored at `f1`, so the private `f` continues to return `true`.

Comment: serious typo in the code.. i've edited my question: it is not the code you assumed it to be.. but rather: `function G(f){return function(){return f;}}`

Comment: @Pacerier, removed bit about definition of G since it looks like your new definition of G will do what you want.  The rest of the post, about how to make the name `g1` always point (modulo masking) to the same function instance is still relevant.

Comment: so even after i've passed the instance of the function called `f1` into an attacker's script, he can do whatever he want to `f1` but at the end of his script i can still call `f1` and say that it will 100% return me true?

Comment: @Pacerier, If `f1` is a local variable (not a global) in your script and you pass `f1` to an attacker's script, he can muck with it's properties, including changing the `call` and `apply` methods, but he cannot change what `f1()` means inside your script.  If you are passing it across frame he can poison the prototype by assigning to `f1.prototype[propertyName]`.

Comment: and is it right to say that even if he did poison the prototype by assigning to `f1.prototype[propertyName]`, I will call `f1()` and it will still give me `true`?

Comment: @Pacerier, If you call `f1` via `f1()` and it either takes zero arguments or you do not call any arguments then it will still give you `true`.  Obviously, if you define a function that calls one of its arguments `var h1 = function (f, x) { return f(x); }` and you pass it to an attacker, they can rename `h1` by doing `h1(eval, "h1=function () { ... }")`.  You should always be suspicious of the value of `this` since an attacker can control that just as easily as any other parameter.

Comment: And you should be wary of storing secrets in the code of any function you pass to an attacker; you don't want `f.toString()` to return something like `function () { var privateKey = "..."; ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

No:

```
var f = new Function("");
f.prop = 1;
```