# Defining read-only properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given an object `obj`, I would like to define a read-only property `'prop'` and set its value to `val`. Is this the proper way to do that?

```
Object.defineProperty( obj, 'prop', {
    get: function () {
        return val;
    }
});
```

The result should be (for `val = 'test'`):

```
obj.prop; // 'test'
obj.prop = 'changed';
obj.prop; // still 'test' since it's read-only
```

This method works btw: http://jsfiddle.net/GHMjN/
I'm just unsure if this is the easiest / smoothest / most proper way to do it...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript (If you don't want to support older browsers, your method is the best)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You could instead use the `writable` property of the property descriptor, which prevents the need for a `get` accessor:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", {
    value: "test",
    writable: false
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `writable` option defaults to `false` so you can omit it in this case:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", {
    value: "test"
});
```

This is ECMAScript 5 so won't work in older browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure if my code and your code produce the exact same result "on the outside", but your method is without doubt the more proper way to do it.

Comment: As per MDN documentation, `Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", {value:"test"});` is equivalent to the code above because writable is set to false by default.

Comment: Note that **subProperties** of an eventual object/array **can still be modified**. Only the "prop" key in this case cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 8):

In new browsers or **node.js** it is possible to use **[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)** to create read-only object.

```
var obj = {
    prop: 'test'
}

obj = new Proxy(obj ,{
    setProperty: function(target, key, value){
        if(target.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return target[key];
        return target[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(target, key){
        return target[key];
    },
    set: function(target, key, value){
        return this.setProperty(target, key, value);
    },
    defineProperty: function (target, key, desc) {
        return this.setProperty(target, key, desc.value);
    },
    deleteProperty: function(target, key) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can still assign new properties to that object, and they would be read-only as well.

**Example**

```
obj.prop
// > 'test'

obj.prop = 'changed';
obj.prop
// > 'test'

// New value
obj.myValue = 'foo';
obj.myValue = 'bar';

obj.myValue
// > 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed an object where we can set its properties only once.
So I made it throw an error when somebody tries to change already set value.

```js
class SetOnlyOnce {
    #innerObj = {}; // private field, not accessible from outside

    getCurrentPropertyName(){
        const stack = new Error().stack; // probably not really performant method
        const name = stack.match(/\[as (\w+)\]/)[1];
        return name;
    }

    getValue(){
        const key = this.getCurrentPropertyName();

        if(this.#innerObj[key] === undefined){
            throw new Error('No global param value set for property: ' + key);
        }

        return this.#innerObj[key];
    }

    setValue(value){
        const key = this.getCurrentPropertyName();

        if(this.#innerObj[key] !== undefined){
            throw new Error('Changing global parameters is prohibited, as it easily leads to errors: ' + key)
        }

        this.#innerObj[key] = value;
    }
}


class GlobalParams extends SetOnlyOnce {
    get couchbaseBucket() { return this.getValue()}
    set couchbaseBucket(value){ this.setValue(value)}

    get elasticIndex() { return this.getValue()}
    set elasticIndex(value){ this.setValue(value)}   
}

const _globalParams = new GlobalParams();

_globalParams.couchbaseBucket = 'some-bucket';
_globalParams.elasticIndex = 'some-index';

console.log(_globalParams.couchbaseBucket)
console.log(_globalParams.elasticIndex)

_globalParams.elasticIndex = 'another-index'; // ERROR is thrown here
console.log(_globalParams.elasticIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

10+ years after this question, ES6 is not a concern even in old browsers. If the object functionality can be satisfied by class construct with static members, then it can be implemented as

```
const obj = class {
  static #prop = "test";
  static get prop() { return obj.#prop }
};

console.log(obj.prop); // test
obj.prop = 'changed';
console.log(obj.prop); // test
```

Note that *class constructs* are [special functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), not objects:

```
typeof obj; // function
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the old browsers (backwards compatibility) I had to come up with accessor functions for properties. I made it part of [bob.js](http://www.bobjs.com):

```
var obj = { };
//declare read-only property.
bob.prop.namedProp(obj, 'name', 'Bob', true);
//declare read-write property.
bob.prop.namedProp(obj, 'age', 1);

//get values of properties.
console.log(bob.string.formatString('{0} is {1} years old.', obj.get_name(), obj.get_age()));
//set value of read-write property.
obj.set_age(2);
console.log(bob.string.formatString('Now {0} is {1} years old.', obj.get_name(), obj.get_age()));

//cannot set read-only property of obj. Next line would throw an error.
// obj.set_name('Rob');

//Output:
//========
// Bob is 1 years old.
// Now Bob is 2 years old.
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Wait, `.namedProp(obj, 'foo')`, creates `.get_foo()`,/`.set_foo()` on the object itself? That's not very efficient. I think I'd go with a wrapper, e.g. `X(obj).set('foo')`/`X(obj).get('foo')`.

Comment: For clarification: I think we are talking about two different things. You possibly want to keep the real object unchanged while having a wrapper around it; but I suggested to change the real object and have functions representing properties. Because for backwards compatibility, old-style JavaScript properties may be treated as fields. Thus, you would need to have accessors (functions) for it (plus I would suggest to remove traditional JS properties from the real object, thus have complete control over the properties). As about wrappers, that's also not bad, but differs from my approach.

Answer (score -3):

I tried and it Works ...

```
element.readOnly = "readOnly"  (then .readonly-> true)
element.readOnly = ""  (then .readonly-> false)
```

Comment: Provide your answer in code snippet. It's not clear enough now

Comment: @Stavros Sfikas, question is not about HTML elements.