# How to check if a value is valid when set property

Tags: javascript, oop

Say I have a fruit class and check the fruit type when constructing:

```
var fruitType = {
  "apple": 0,
  "orange": 1
};

fruit = function(name) {
  if (name in fruitType) {
    this.name = name;
  } else {
    throw "wrong fruit type";
  }
};
```

but I can't avoid the property being set after the object's construction:

```
var f = new fruit("apple");
f.name = "orange"; // ok
f.name = "cat"; // expecting this does nothing, f.name is still "orange"
```

How to do the checking and keep the property unchanged?

Comment: maybe this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757337/defining-read-only-properties-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using getter and setter functions rather that using the properties directly:

```
var fruitType = {
  "apple": 0,
  "orange": 1
};

var fruit = function(name) {
  this.setName(name);
};

fruit.prototype.getName = function(){
  return this.name;
}

fruit.prototype.setName = function(name){
  if (name in fruitType) {
    this.name = name;
  } else {
    throw "wrong fruit type";
  }
};
```

You could still override `f.name` directly, but so long as you are consistent and use your setters you won't run into problems.

```
var f = new fruit("apple");
f.setName('orange'); // OK
f.setName('toast'); // Throws an error
f.name = 'toast'; // This works, so don't do it!
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h7RJ/) (Thanks The Dark Knight)

If it is important that `f.name = 'toast'` does not work for you then you can use separate functions for every fruit object along with a privately scoped `name` variable:

```
var fruitType = {
  "apple": 0,
  "orange": 1
};

var fruit = function(name) {

  this.getName = function(){
    return name;
  }

  this.setName = function(newName){
    if (newName in fruitType) {
      name = newName;
    } else {
      throw "wrong fruit type";
    }
  };

  this.setName(name);

};
```

This has the disadvantage of every fruit needing it's own copies of the functions, but it has the advantage that the only way to modify the `name` variable is using the setter:

```
var f = new fruit("apple");
f.setName('orange'); // OK
f.setName('toast'); // Throws an error
f.name = 'toast'; // This sets the `name` property to 'toast', but:
f.getName(); // this will still return 'orange'
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Upjcv/3/)

Comment: Hope you don't mind, i just added the fiddle for your code in your answer.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I don't mind, but I was editing my post at the same time, so it didn't go through.

Comment: Added the fiddle again .

Comment: Thanks. But the test case against my code is to check `f.name = x`, the getter/setter option can't satisfy test case.

Comment: Well if you can't modify your test case you can still do what you want but only in browsers supporting defineProperty (an ES5 feature).

Answer (score 1):

Use getters and setters:

```
this.getValue = function(){
    return value;
};

this.setValue = function(val){
    value = val;
};
```

Add your checking logic to the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Paulpro's idea, here is my version:

```
fruit = function(name) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    get: function() { return this.nameValue; },
    set: function(v) {
      if (v in fruitType) {
        this.nameValue = v;
      }
    }
  });

  if (name in fruitType) {
    this.name = name;
  } else {
    throw "wrong fruit type";
  }
};
```