# Readonly property in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a cache service, i would like to store data in it.

```
angular.module('core').service('markerCache', function(){
    var cache = [];
    this.set_cache = function(arr){
        cache = arr;
        this.cached = true;
    };
    this.cached = false; //this must be read-only and must be property, not function
});
```

And i also would like to define read-only(value can be set only inside service) property in angular services(factory, service) if possible, if not - any workaround would be awesome.
[There is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757337/defining-read-only-properties-in-javascript) a way to define read-only properties in javascript, but how to do it in angular way?
By read-only i mean setting value inside service. For example

```
angular.module('core').controller('Ctrl', function($scope, markerCache){
    markerCache.cached = false; //disable setter outside of markerCache service
});
```

### Update, for those who is still interested, here's working service

```
angular.module('core').service('markerCache', function(){
    var cache = [];
    var cached = false;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "cache", {
        get: function() {
            return cache;
        },
        set: function(val){
            cache = val;
            cached = true;
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "cached", {
        get: function() {
            return cached;
        },
        set: angular.noop
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use closure to hide a variable and expose a property using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to read the variable.

```
angular.module('core').service('markerCache', function(){
    var cache = [];
    var cached = false; // private variable
    this.set_cache = function(arr){
        cache = arr;
        cached = true;
    };
    Object.defineProperty(this, "cached", { // public readonly getter
      get: function() {
        return cached;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        //throw new Error('Cannot set internal cache state'); //throw custom exception
      }
      //set: angular.noop //or do nothing, empty setter
    })
});
```

Comment: Good solution, any workaround to get rid of `Cannot set property cached of [object Object] which has only a getter`, i mean this is correct and exact? But how to show custom message?

Comment: Most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [AngularJS constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant)?

> **constant(name, value)**; Register a constant service, such as a string,
>   a number, an array, an object or a function, with the $injector.
>   Unlike value it can be injected into a module configuration function
>   (see angular.Module) and it cannot be overridden by an Angular
>   decorator.

Answer (score 0):

The variable should not be associated with `this` context, you could make it private by making it `var cached`, also defining `getter` inside your service for getting value of `cache` so that consumer will access that value by `getter` function.

```
angular.module('core').service('markerCache', function(){
    var cache = [], 
        cached = false; //made privet
    this.set_cache = function(arr){
        cache = arr;
        cached = true;
    };
    this.getCache = function(){
        return cached;
    }
});
```