# Why is the name property a different value from what I set it to?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. Can someone explain why I'm getting an unexpected value when I access the `name` property of the `person` function?

```js
var name = function() {
    console.log('name');
}

function person() {
    console.log('hello person');
}

person.name = "hello";

console.log(person.name); // logs "person"
```

Answer (score 4):

Functions have a "name" property that defaults to the, erm, `name` of the function itself. It can be accessed but not written to, so your assignment to `person.name` is ignored.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: thnks fr d answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) is a non-writable and non-enumerable property defined for functions. So even though you

```js
person.name = "hello";
```

Its not getting over-written. It returns the function name.

Answer (score 1):

If you check `name` [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) you will see that it's not writable:

```js
function person() {
    console.log('hello person');
}

var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person, 'name');

console.log(descriptor);
```

As you can see it has `"writable": false`, which means that you can't change `name` of the function.

Comment: "immutable" !== non-writable.

Comment: @torazaburo Ops, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can define readonly(`writable: false`) properties. Hence, the `name` property is one of them. For futher you can check this link out.

[Defining read-only properties in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757337/defining-read-only-properties-in-javascript)

[Define Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 1):

Check the `defineProperty` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description)

It is possible to define a property which is non-enumerable and non-writable through assignment operator

> **writable**
>
> true if and only if the value associated with the property may be
>   changed with an assignment operator.

and

> enumerable
>
> true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the
>   properties on the corresponding object.

[name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) is one such property of `function` object.

> Writable      **no**
>
> Enumerable    **no**
>
> Configurable  **yes**