# Lock Privileged Method in OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I just curious about this question in my head about lock/fixed method in oop javascript. This is the example :

```
function Counter() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.increaseCount = function() {
    this.count++;
  }
  this.displayCount = function() {
    console.log(this.count);
  }
}
var counter1 = new Counter();
counter1.increaseCount = function() {
  this.count += 2;
}
counter1.increaseCount();
counter1.displayCount(); // 2
```

How to lock/fixed method so it cannot be changed by instances? In example I want to lock increase method always add one.

Edit : I think its different from read-only properties, because it's property. I very curious about method lock/fixed in javascript. Even i use

```
Object.defineProperty(Counter.prototype, 'increaseCountt', {
  get: function() { this.count++; },
  writtable: false
});
```

i called it "counter1.increaseCountt" not "counter1.increaseCountt()" because it's not method.

When i used Object.freeze after creating instance like this:

```
var counter1 = new Counter();
Object.freeze(counter1);
```

the count result always zero.

Comment: Create an instance factory and Object.freeze the instance before returing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining read-only properties in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757337/defining-read-only-properties-in-javascript)

Comment: I think that only for properties, even i use "get" function to call function it's still property @lealceldeiro

Comment: Did, the suggestion made by @Derek朕會功夫 work for you? It seems fine to me. What do you say about it?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 sorry i didnt understand when to add Object.freeze, can you explain again

Comment: @lealceldeiro have you tried it? because when i add Object.freeze "this.count" is always zero

Comment: Perhaps you can also make the property non editable but this is a horrible design choice.