# Why I am not able to set to document or window object in js?

Tags: javascript, dom, window, document

When I inspected and in console I wrote `window.document = null;` or `window = null;`. This do not assign null for respective props, why such behaviour?

If so, then can I explicitly disable any object or it's property from setting and only enable it to get data (just like what we have in C# - properties with only getter)

Comment: They are readonly properties. Imagine if you could set the `document` to null - you would completely break the DOM. What is your actual goal here?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Defining read-only properties in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7757337)

Comment: Retrieving [the descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) of `document` gives `Object { get: document(), set: undefined, enumerable: true, configurable: false }`, this tells that the said property is a getter without a setter, and its descriptor can't be configured.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no specific goal here, was just experimenting unusual things. I was using these objects from so long and today I got to know that I can't assign to these objects.