# Create a read-only/immutable copy of any object (including deep properties)

Tags: javascript, object, constants, immutability, readonly

How can I create a read-only/immutable version of an object in JavaScript, whose properties cannot be changed? This this should also apply to the properties of any sub objects and so on.

All methods I have come across to do this (`Object.defineProperty`, `Object.freeze`, etc) work only for the top level properties of the object, but not for the sub-objects.

(A possible use case: After creating/modifying a `settings` or `configuration` type object in a specific module, you need to expose it to the rest of the program's modules in an immutable form.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with after some thought. Works well for my needs so I thought I'd share it QnA style. 
Do suggest any improvements/issues if you you find them.

```
/**
 * Make the the specified object (deeply) immutable or "read-only", so that none of its
 * properties (or sub-properties) can be modified. The converted object is returned.
 * @param {object} obj Input object
 */
makeImmutable: function makeImmutable (obj) {
    if ((typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null) ||
        (Array.isArray? Array.isArray(obj): obj instanceof Array) ||
        (typeof obj === "function")) {

        Object.freeze(obj);

        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                makeImmutable(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

EDIT:
Simplified the code. Also handles arrays correctly now.

Comment: Great solution.  I created a code snippet below using the solution to show how it is used and the proof. `Upvoted`

Answer (score 0):

Intrigued by this solution.

### Here is the code snippet with an example:

```js
/**
 * Make the the specified object (deeply) immutable or "read-only", so that none of its
 * properties (or sub-properties) can be modified. The converted object is returned.
 * @param {object} obj Input object
 */
makeImmutable: function makeImmutable(obj) {
  if ((typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null) ||
    (Array.isArray ? Array.isArray(obj) : obj instanceof Array) ||
    (typeof obj === "function")) {

    Object.freeze(obj);

    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        makeImmutable(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

var newObj = {
  thisArrayOfObjects: [{
    propertyOne: 'value1',
    propertyTwo: 'value2'
  }]
};
newObj.thisArrayOfObjects.push({
  propertyBefore: 'before3'
});


console.log('newObj', newObj);
$('#viewer').append('newObj: ' + JSON.stringify(newObj));

makeImmutable(newObj);

console.log('imutable', newObj);
$('#viewer').append('<br/><br/>imutable: ' + JSON.stringify(newObj));
try {
  newObj.thisArrayOfObjects.push({
    propertyThree: 'value3'
  });
} catch (e) {
  $('#viewer').append('<br/><br/>immutable error: ' + e.message);
  console.log('immutable error:', e.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answers already. This one is using [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/):

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

To make an object immutable:

```
/**
 * Makes an Object immutable by (deep) freezing all own peoperties.
 * @param {*} obj - Object to make immutable.
 * @returns {*} The input Object.
 */
function deepFreeze(obj) {
    if (_.isObject(obj) || _.isArray(obj) || _.isFunction(obj)) {
        Object.freeze(obj);
        _.forOwn(obj, deepFreeze);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

To make an immutable clone:

```
var frozenClone = deepFreeze(_.cloneDeep(obj));
```