# Is it possible to create read only members in JavaScript Object Literal Notation?

Tags: javascript

I have following JavaScript Object Literal Notiation object

```
var Parameters= {
    modal_window:{
        backdrop:true,
        keyboard:true,
        show:true,
        remote:false,
        type:{
            normal:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-primary';
                this.header.type='modal-header';
            },
            success:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-success';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert alert-success';
            },
            info:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-info';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert alert-info';
            },
            error:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-danger';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert alert-error';
            },
            warning:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-warning';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert';
            }
        }
    },
    header:{
        title:undefined,
        type:this.window.type.normal.header
    },
    footer:{
        button:
        {
            accept:{
                title:'Accept',
                click:undefined,
                type:undefined
            },
            cancel:{
                title:'Cancel',
                click:undefined
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Is it possible to make header.type and footer.button.accept.type read only variables which can be changed only through window.type.normal, window.type.success and etc.?

> **Clarifications:**
>   I want to make some clarifications here. My Parameters.header.type
>   should be read only and should have default value. And when user
>   selects for example Parameters.modal_window.type.normal
>   Parameters.header.type must be changed.

Comment: no, read-only is not possible in javascript.

Comment: Shouldn't name one of your variables, objects, functions, pretty much anything `window`.

Comment: read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: Read only is possible with `Object.defineProperty`, or my using functions with closures.

Comment: @Paul Draper can you give some example as answer?

Comment: Well I would if your code made sense, but when this.window.type.normal.header is called, `this` is the global context  (window).

Comment: And another thing, how is this a prototype design pattern?

Comment: @PaulDraper Sorry I made mistake it is Object Literal Notation. :(

Comment: @PaulDraper How I can improve it?

Comment: @andy I think it actually is possible in modern JavaScript runtimes (with getter/setter support).

Comment: @antindexer Have a look at the second part of my answer. I believe this is exactly what you want.

Comment: @plax I looking and trying it in browser in order to check which is suitable to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite what everyone says, you can create read-only properties in modern browsers that supports `Object.defineProperty`.

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'someProp', {
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: 'initial value'
});

obj.someProp = 'some other value';

console.log(obj.someProp); //initial value
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your question again, I understand that you meant true private members or private variables. That can be accomplished by making use of closures and custom getters/setters.

*Note: I simplified your object's structure for the sake of the example.*

```
var Parameters = (function () {
    var headerType = 'some value'; //private variable

    return {
        modal_window: {
            type: {
                normal: function () {
                    //custom logic
                    headerType = 'some new value'; //set private variable
                }
            }
        },
        header: {
            get type() { return headerType; } //define a getter only

            //for older browsers, you could just define a normal function
            //which you would have to access like Parameters.header.type()
            //type: function () { return headerType; }
        }
    };

})();

var header = Parameters.header;

console.log(header.type); //some value
header.type = 'some other val';
console.log(header.type); //some value
Parameters.modal_window.type.normal();
console.log(header.type); //some new value
```

Now that we know it is possible to enforce true privacy, I am not sure it's really worth it.  Enforcing true privacy complicates the design and reduces testability (depending on the case). An approach that is far popular as well is to simply identify private members using a naming convention such as `_myPrivateVar`. This clearly indicates the itention and tells the programmers that they should treat that member like a private one.

Comment: This is working perfectly i up voted your answer. I just trying others answers also. So please wait for my decision.

Comment: @antindexer Did you forget? ;)

Comment: The problem with this is that non-writable (read-only) properties cannot be written by *any* code.  The OP isn't looking for that kind of solution, the way I read it.

Comment: @Pointy, The second part of the answer allows the variable to be modified.

Comment: @plalx yes, ok I see that. That's more-or-less what my answer did too.

Answer (score 3):

You could make them functions, like this:

```
header:{
        title:undefined,
        type: function(){
           return Parameters.modal_window.type.normal.header;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't make them read-only, but I think this is in the spirit of what the op is trying to achieve.

Comment: @pax162 How i can change it than from other function?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support IE 8 or earlier, you could create an accessor method that retrieves the value and then use a private variable to store the actual data.  If you define your methods appropriately, the private variable could be set from them, but not set by the outside world.  In IE8, there is no ability to define a read-only property so you'd have to use an accessor instead.

See Crockford's treatise on private member data: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html for details on how to set up the private data that your accessor could be an interface for.

If you're willing to require IE9 or greater, then you could use a getter via `Object.defineProperty()` combined with a private variable in a closure.  If there was no setter, then it couldn't be set from the outside world, but methods defined within the closure (described in Crockford's article) could still set the value of the private variable.  You would have a read-only property that could also be set by a few of your own methods.

Comment: That predates the advent of getter and setter definitions, doesn't it?

Comment: @Pointy - how do you store something privately and then access it only from certain methods without a closure concept as described in crockford's article?

Comment: You can do it with a closure, so of course that part is accurate. With getters and setters you can make it look like there's a property there by making the getter fetch the closure value. The setter can either do nothing, or do some validation, or whatever.

Comment: @Pointy - sounds right.  Closure plus getter would give you a read-only property that you could modify from other methods defined within the closure.  As I understand it, using these features in `Object.defineProperty()` forces you to IE9 or greater so one would have to be OK with that too.

Comment: Why the downvote?  What's not accurate in this post and comments?

Comment: @Pointy - added an additional option to the answer based on our comment discussion.

Comment: @jfriend00 Haven't downvoted, but I could say that the words aren't accurate "read-only properties that can only by changed...". By definition a *read-only* property can never be changed. It certainly doesn't deserve a downvote however...

Comment: @plalx - that's what the OP is asking for.  A property that is read-only to the outside world, but can be modified only by methods they define.  I'll tweak the wording a bit.

Comment: @jfriend00 I did not down voted your answer if it makes sense for you. However through the answers I saw methods to make it possible and statement like "Javascript doesn't have the ability to define read-only properties that can only be changed by certain methods." dose not make sense.

Comment: @antindexer - OK, wording removed/changed again.  I was hoping the focus could be more on the content of the actual suggestions.

Comment: @jfriend00 you removed unnecessary party it is good. However you down voted my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and set it as non-writable. Your constructor would have to replace the values with the properties. If the variable that the property is returning is captured in a closure and not exposed to anything else, it will be as good as read-only. If it is not changed, you don't even need a closure, just use the `value` configuration option.

EDIT: As per your demand,

```
var Properties = function(obj) {
    var makePropRecursive = function(prop) {
        var old_prop = obj[prop];
        delete obj[prop];
        var prop_obj = {};
        for (var attr in old_prop) {
            if (old_prop.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                Object.defineProperty(prop_obj, attr, {
                    value: old_prop[attr],
                    writable: false,
                    enumerable: true
                });
            }
        }
        Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
            value: prop_obj,
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true
        });
    };
    makePropRecursive('header');
    makePropRecursive('footer');
    return obj;
};

var props = new Properties({
    modal_window:{
        backdrop:true,
        keyboard:true,
        show:true,
        remote:false,
        type:{
            normal:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-primary';
                this.header.type='modal-header';
            },
            success:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-success';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert alert-success';
            },
            info:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-info';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert alert-info';
            },
            error:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-danger';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert alert-error';
            },
            warning:function(){
                this.footer.button.accept.type='btn btn-warning';
                this.header.type='modal-header alert';
            }
        }
    },
    header:{
        title:"Whatever",
        type:"Type"
    },
    footer:{
        button:
        {
            accept:{
                title:'Accept',
                click:undefined,
                type:undefined
            },
            cancel:{
                title:'Cancel',
                click:undefined
            }
        }
    }
});

console.log(props.header);
props.header = 17;
props.header.type = 18;
props.header.title = 19;
console.log(props.header);
```

`props.header` is unchanged: output shows

```
Object {title: "Whatever", type: "Type"}
Object {title: "Whatever", type: "Type"}
```

It's 3am and the recursive function isn't, so you can only "fix" one level of one object; also, it would be better if the values were copied onto `this` rather than returning `obj`; but it should not be too hard to polish it up.

If you need to have the values changeable, you can set up a private copy of the whole object inside the constructor, then make a getter (`get: function(name) { return stuff.from.the.original.object }`).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question like I first did.

Comment: @plalx: Yeah, went with static readonly attributes. Last paragraph briefly explains how to do it for privately writeable readonly attributes, but I really need my sleep :p You got an upvote from me as soon as I read it, if it means anything.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of JavaScript, you can define how property access works:

```
var yourObj = function() {
  var readOnly = "cannot be changed";
  return {
    get readOnly() { return readOnly; },
    set readOnly(v) { return; },

    specialSetter: function(something) {
      if (something == "magic number") {
        readOnly = "oops maybe it can";
      }
    }
  };
}();
```

Now code can get the value like this:

```
var theValue = yourObj.readOnly;
```

without having to make a function call. However, if it tries to change the value:

```
yourObj.readOnly = "hello world";
```

then nothing will happen.

Either the setter or any other function can, when it wants to, still update the value that'll be returned when accessing the "readOnly" property. However, any attempt to just set the property directly will do nothing (unless the setter function decides it likes the value).

*edit* you'd want to make "specialSetter" be read-only probably, though nothing will be able to "break in" to the closure. Also, you *might* want to use Object.defineProperty to make "readOnly" not be writable, but I don't know whether that'd work out properly.

Comment: What do you think of enforcing true privacy vs using a naming convention such as `_myPrivateMember`?

Comment: Well this sample code gets pretty close to true privacy. I think naming conventions are not aesthetically satisfying ;)

Comment: Yeah I kinda feel the same, however I have the feeling that most libraries out there wont bother implementing true private members, at least from what i've seen so far. It's too sad we have to make the choice between writing memory-efficient code and real encapsulated code. I am actually just enforcing privacy for private module members, but never for *classes*.

Answer (score 1):

How about: `Object.freeze()`

You can find out more here: [MDN Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

So:

```
Object.freeze(Parameters.modal_window.header);
...
```

Then in your your function that you want to be able to set them, you unfreeze them, change them, and re-freeze them.

You absolutely won't be able to change the frozen objects, by mistake anywhere else in your program.

This works in IE9+ chrome, firefox, and safari.

Comment: Then *nothing* can alter the property.  That's not quite the same as having a private property that can be set only under the control of a setter function (which might apply validation rules or whatever).

Comment: @Pointy Well, he didn't say he wanted a private property, he said he wanted a readOnly property. Which this accomplishes.

Comment: The last sentence talks about the properties being changeable but only via some explicit APIs.

Comment: I want to make this parameter read only from outside. I do not need private member. It should be accessible from outside to read not for write.

Comment: @antindexer Right. You want control over how the property can be changed; for example, to check whether it's numeric or something like that.

Comment: @antindexer that's what this will accomplish, and has a little more support then `object.defineProperty`, but if you don't need lots of support, then you should go with @plalx answer.

Comment: @ryan it needs to be accessible and writable from other functions on the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following revealing module pattern to hide variables and keep them from being changed but this wont stop anyone from changing the accessible "type" function.

Below in the code, the header property was changed to _header and made into a function.  The property type was changed to _type and hidden by wrapping a return with an object notation to return "type" as a function instead of the property. Someone can change the type function to anything they want by over writing it, but they can't change the value of _type.

```
var Parameters = function () {
var _modal_window = function modal_window() {
    var backdrop = true,
    keyboard = true,
    show = true,
    remote = false;
    return {
        type: {
            normal: function () {
                this.footer.button.accept.type = 'btn btn-primary';
                this.header.type = 'modal-header';
            },
            success: function () {
                this.footer.button.accept.type = 'btn btn-success';
                this.header.type = 'modal-header alert alert-success';
            },
            info: function () {
                this.footer.button.accept.type = 'btn btn-info';
                this.header.type = 'modal-header alert alert-info';
            },
            error: function () {
                this.footer.button.accept.type = 'btn btn-danger';
                this.header.type = 'modal-header alert alert-error';
            },
            warning: function () {
                this.footer.button.accept.type = 'btn btn-warning';
                this.header.type = 'modal-header alert';
            }
        }
    };
}();
var _header = function header() {
    var _type = 'This causes error';//this.window.type.normal.header;
    return {
        title: undefined, type: function () { return _type; }
    };
}();
var _footer = function footer() {
    return {
        button:
    {
        accept: {
            title: 'Accept',
            click: undefined,
            type: undefined
        },
        cancel: {
            title: 'Cancel',
            click: undefined
        }
    }
    };
}();
return {
    modal_window: _modal_window,
    header: _header,
    footer: _footer
};
}();
```