# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with node.js, and in one of my js files I'm using `const` in `"strict mode"`. When trying to run it, I'm getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

What is the best practice to do this?

Edit:

```
'use strict'
const MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 1024*1024; // 1 MB
```

Comment: @thefourtheye check in chrome, ff is working fine.

Comment: use `var`. Add semikolon `'use strict';`

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Actually I am using Node.js yaar. It works fine in that.

Comment: Aah... Fails in [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/i5gv9D)

Comment: After updating the latest Node version v5.3.0, it works well now.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio and seeing this issue check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/44120850/681009

Comment: I had this problem while using http-server. The version that caused problem was 0.12.0. After specifying http-server version 0.11.1, the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 293):

The `const` and `let` are part of ECMAScript 2015 (a.k.a. ES6 and Harmony), and was not enabled by default in Node.js 0.10 or 0.12. Since Node.js 4.x, “All shipping [ES2015] features, which V8 considers stable, are turned on by default on Node.js and do NOT require any kind of runtime flag.”. [Node.js docs has an overview of what ES2015 features are enabled by default, and which who require a runtime flag](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/). So by upgrading to Node.js 4.x or newer the error should disappear.

To enable some of the ECMAScript 2015 features (including `const` and `let`) in Node.js 0.10 and 0.12; start your node program with a harmony flag, otherwise you will get a syntax error. For example:

```
node --harmony app.js
```

It all depends on which side your strict js is located. I would recommend using strict mode with `const` declarations on your server side and start the server with the harmony flag. For the client side, you should use [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) or similar tool to convert ES2015 to ES5, since not all client browsers support the `const` declarations.

Comment: This is the most complete and relevant answer.

Comment: Strict mode can also applied using a flag (rather than a literal expression)
node --harmony --use_strict app.js
Which is nice.

Comment: I would like to advice against using the "use_strict" flag. It's running someone else's code in an interpreter that it wasn't written for.
Always use `'use strict';` yourself, but let third party code decide for itself.

Comment: FWIW I've found the same issue running node v8.1 but armfh version (raspberry pi).

Answer (score 242):

If this is happening in nodejs, it is due to the older version of nodejs. Update node by using,

1) Clear NPM's cache:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

2) Install a little helper called 'n'

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

3) Install latest stable NodeJS version

```
sudo n stable
```

Update nodejs instructions taken from, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407/698072

Comment: I got this "npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: n@2.1.4" while trying to do step 2. Good times.

Comment: Apparently this DOESN'T WORK ON WINDOWS.Alternative is just to reinstall node from their site.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you may find it safer to specify the `node` version. For example, as of the time of this writing, `sudo n 6.9.4` will install the latest LTS, where `sudo n stable` will install `7.4.0`. Obviously, that's a breaking change, so take care with `n stable`. Alternatively, `sudo n lts` installs the most recent LTS.

Comment: Works on centos 6.5. Earlier I was getting the following error " SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode ". Thanks

Comment: This resolved the issue for me on a legacy machine where the --harmony flag did not.
Setup: Trying to launch a screen npm start monitor using scripts in crontab caused the strict error where running it from the cli did not.

Previous node version was 0.10.48 running on ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

I followed this step and the one changing the softlink /usr/bin/node from  /etc/alternatives/node to /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.0.0/bin/node
and everything just worked.

Thank you for this!

Comment: Badass thanks for this, it not only solved that problem but all the inherent little foibles when building SCA Local

Answer (score 24):

Usually this error occurs when the version of node against which the code is being executed is older than expected. (i.e. 0.12 or older).

if you are using nvm than please ensure that you have the right version of node being used. You can check the [compatibility on node.green for const under strict mode](http://node.green/#ES2015-bindings-const-redefining-a-const--strict-mode-)

I found a similar issue on another post and posted my answer [there in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932038/husky-giving-error-syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode/44168690#44168690)

Comment: I ran into this when running my Node project in WebStorm. My local version in the repo was running Node 8.2.1, but WebStorm looked at my `/usr/bin/node` folder, which had 0.10.46.

Answer (score 20):

One important step after you update your node is to link your node binary to the latest installed node version

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.0.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: How can I figure out which version just got installed?

Comment: You can find where your current version of node is installed by running `which node`

Comment: Also you will have seen the directory when running "n stable"

In this line:
mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.0.0

So you could just go to /usr/local/n/versions/node/ and see what directories exist.

Comment: @JoseLlausas `node --version` prints out the version number e.g. `v0.10.29`

Answer (score 15):

This is probably not the solution for everyone, but it was for me.

If you are using NVM, you might not have enabled the right version of node for the code you are running.  After you reboot, your default version of node changes back to the system default.

Was running into this when working with react-native which had been working fine.  Just use nvm to use the right version of node to solve this problem.

Comment: and any code to illustrate your stated "solution" above?

Comment: yes, this was my initial issue. although i had to switch to another linux server anyway due to node and gcc version compatibility issues on an outdated centos version.

Comment: @Kermit_ice_tea  The same code in the question.  The bug is in the version of node, using NVM to set it to a version that does not have that bug makes that code pass.  `nvm use version-number-you-need` is all you have to do.

Answer (score 8):

Since the time the question was asked, the draft for the `const` keyword is already a living standard as part of [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations). Also the current version of Node.js [supports const declarations](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/#which-es6-features-ship-with-node-js-by-default-no-runtime-flag-required) without the `--harmony` flag.

With the above said you can now run `node app.js`, with `app.js`:

```
'use strict';
const MB = 1024 * 1024;
...
```

getting both the syntax sugar and the benefits of strict mode.

Comment: A megabyte `MB` is a power of ten, while a mebibyte `MiB` is a power of two. i.e. `1MB = 1e6` and `1MiB = 1024 * 1024`. See wikipedia: [Mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and ended up in this Q&A. This is not the solution the OP was looking for but may help others with a similar issue.

I'm using [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to run a project and in a given staging server I had a really old version of Node, NPM and PM2. I updated everything, however, I kept keeping the same error:

> SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

I tried to stop and start the application several times. Also tried to update everything again. Nothing worked. Until I noticed a warning when I ran `pm2 start`:

> **>>>> In-memory PM2 is out-of-date, do:**
>   **>>>> $ pm2 update**
>   In memory PM2 version: 0.15.10
>   Local PM2 version: 3.2.9

Gotcha! After running `pm2 update`, I finally was able to get the application running as expected. No "const in strict mode" errors anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was using pm2 to start and maintain the node processes.

From the CLI it worked perfectly.

```
which node
/usr/local/bin/node
node -v
v10.15.0
```

However, I set up a cronjob and I got the syntax error.

Then wrote a cronjob to check `which node` and `node -v` and surprisingly, it was a different path and version.

```
which node
/usr/bin/node
node -v
v0.10.48
```

To fix the cronjob I had to use the flag `--interpreter` for pm2, like so:

```
pm2 start dist/server.js --interpreter=/usr/local/bin/node
```

Answer (score -2):

The use of `const` in strict mode is available with the release of Chrome 41.
Currently, [Chrome 41 Beta is already released](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/01/chrome-41-beta-new-es6-features-and.html) and supports it.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wanted to comment that since the OP asked for Node.js, browser compatibility isn't relevant. Yet somehow the answer had 4 upvotes, and it obscured other more relevant answers.

Answer (score -3):

```
cd /
npm install -g nave
nave use 6.11.1
node app.js
```

Comment: For linux server

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When contributing an answer, it's best to give both some code *and* an explanation.

Comment: Down vote because there is no explanation. why nave package should be installed ..

Comment: Why would such a solution work? An explanation is needed.

Comment: Although there is no explanation, for me the error only solved after running the commands described here: `npm install -g nave;  nave use 6.11.1`

+1

Answer (score -4):

const is not supported by ECMAScript. So after you specify strict mode, you get syntax error. You need to use var instead of const if you want your code to be compatible with all browsers. I know, not the ideal solution, but it is what it is. There are ways to create read-only properties in JavaScript (see [Can Read-Only Properties be Implemented in Pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript)) but I think it might be overkill depending on your scenario.

Below is browser compatibility note from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

**Browser compatibility**

> The current implementation of const is a Mozilla-specific extension
>   and is not part of ECMAScript 5. It is supported in Firefox & Chrome
>   (V8). As of Safari 5.1.7 and Opera 12.00, if you define a variable
>   with const in these browsers, you can still change its value later. It
>   is not supported in Internet Explorer 6-10, but is included in
>   Internet Explorer 11. The const keyword currently declares the
>   constant in the function scope (like variables declared with var).
>
> Firefox, at least since version 13, throws a TypeError if you
>   redeclare a constant. None of the major browsers produce any notices
>   or errors if you assign another value to a constant. The return value
>   of such an operation is that of the new value assigned, but the
>   reassignment is unsuccessful only in Firefox and Chrome (at least
>   since version 20).
>
> const is going to be defined by ECMAScript 6, but with different
>   semantics. Similar to variables declared with the let statement,
>   constants declared with const will be block-scoped.

Comment: `const` is supported in ECMAScript 6 and it is widely supported: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#const But you're right in your answer - `'use strict';` and `const` does not mix.

Comment: A quick test shows that `const` is re-declarable in Safari 7 but not in Opera 21, Chrome 35 and Firefox 29.

Comment: **Browse compatibility** is of no concern... this is _Node.js_