# How do you declare a 'const' in react-native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I keep getting an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`

I think it is because I have a line like this:

```
    const shouldSet = touches.length === 1;
    if (shouldSet) {
      const { onPanBegin } = this.props;
```

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2015-10-23**: as of React Native v0.13.0-rc `const` [is now enabled](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2955).

React Native's JavaScript environment is not a browser, instead it uses [JavaScriptCore](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore). Anything that isn't supported natively needs to be transformed down to a subset of JS that JavaScriptCore supports, and React Native uses [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to do that. Here are the transformations that React Native uses (as of 2015-07-31):

ES5

- Reserved Words: promise.catch(function() { });

ES6

- Arrow functions
- Call spread
- Classes
- Destructuring
- Computed Properties
- Object Consise Method
- Object Short Notation
- Rest Params
- Template Literals:

ES7

- Object Spread
- Function Trailing Comma

It is not immediately clear to me why constants aren't included in this list, and it appears that support for overriding it still isn't quite ready:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1451

Answer (score 0):

At the moment `const` keyword is not supported in react-native android, I hope it will be available with the next release of react-native. The fix was trivial, for more details look into origin [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2932).

Answer (score 0):

you need get the lastest version of react-native.

pod 'React', '0.13.0-rc'