# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode (trying to run Ionic app)

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run my app using Ionic, but when I type the following:

```
ionic build android
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Any ideas how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using:

1) Clear NPM's cache:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

2) Install a little helper called 'n'

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

3) Install latest stable NodeJS version

```
sudo n stable
```

Update nodejs instructions taken from, [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with ionic.

You need to update to the latest version of node.js and that should take care of the error. See this [similar issue](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/758) on the joi node module.