# Firebase Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am getting error while deploying error on Firebase.
According to this docs: [Firebase Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html)

I have installed Node and npm latest version.

Then I run "npm install -g firebase-tools" command for firebase. After this, When ever I run "firebase --help" or "firebase init" Then got this error :

[image]

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode

Comment: @jpw Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me steps to remove this error, I  don't know much about node.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you as I don't know Node that well either, I just thought that the question I linked would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Updating **node** will resolve this issue. Install the LTS version of node from [their website](https://nodejs.org/en/).

**OR**

Replace the `const` from `const EventEmitter` with `var`