# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login on facebook.com with selenium-webdriver.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/login');
driver.findElement(By.id('email')).sendKeys('****');
driver.findElement(By.id('pass')).sendKeys('*****');
driver.findElement(By.id('loginbutton')).click();

driver.findElement(By.linkText('Settings')).then(function(element) {
  console.log('Yes, found the element');
}, function(error) {
  console.log('The element was not found, as expected');
});
driver.quit();
```

It is giving error:

> ```
> /home/shubham/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:25
> const builder = require('./builder');
> ^^^^^
> SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
>     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>     at require (module.js:380:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shubham/Music/amazon_login/test_22_4_16/sel_login.js:1:79)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
> ```

`node --version`  v0.10.37

`npm  --version`1.4.28

`protractor --version`  Version 3.2.2

selenium-webdriver@2.53.1

Comment: You definitely want to update your nodejs ) _Or downgrade the selenium driver_ _Or start with `--harmony` flag_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23151062/1918648

Comment: after try `nodejs --harmony app.js `   it is giving error `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio and encountering this issue, see this question/answer first: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44120850/681009

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Updating `nodejs` solved the issue:

```
npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
node --version
node app.js
```

You have to run the second and third command as root/administrator.

Comment: I noticed you use `nodejs` as command line. It should be `node`. Can you print the "node --version"?

Comment: node --version && 
  nodejs --version && 
  whereis node && 
  /usr/local/bin/node --version && 
  sudo mv node node_0_12_2 && 
  whereis nodejs && 
  sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs node

Comment: Above solution only updates the node version which would have updated the node version from `v0.10.37` to a newer version which is 4 or later which supports `const` in strict mode so the error would have resolved. A proper solution can be found under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932038/husky-giving-error-syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode/44168690#44168690

Comment: Updating NodeJS solves this problem. But, After running `sudo npm install -g n` you might get following error:

`npm: relocation error: npm: symbol SSL_set_cert_cb, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference`  In order to overcome this error, try upgrading openssl using the below command:

`sudo yum update openssl`

Answer (score 12):

`n stable` wouldn't do the trick for me. On the other hand,

```
nvm install stable
```

That actually got me to last nodejs version. Apparently `n stable` won't get pass `v0.12.14` for me. I really don't know why.

Note: `nvm` is Node Version Manager, you can install it from [its github page](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown). Thanks @isaiah for noting that `nvm` is not a known command.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was more simple to solve, just going to the [Node](http://nodejs.org) web site, get and install the LTS version.

Answer (score 2):

Update your `node` and it will resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating NodeJS solves this problem.
But, after running `sudo npm install -g n` you might get following error:

```
npm: relocation error: npm: symbol SSL_set_cert_cb, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference
```

In order to overcome this error, try upgrading openssl using the below command:

```
sudo yum update openssl
```

Answer (score -3):

That error means your node's publish is low than the need.
carefully to update the node of your computer.