# Can't run Protractor tests via Grunt on Teamcity while can locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, protractor, teamcity

I'm trying to run my `test-build` on TeamCity using just `grunt` command, but it throw me error. The odd thing is - when I write `grunt` command in my terminal locally (not on Teamcity agent) all works fine. I've got input like *this*:

```
impregnable@linux-dev-ort:~/dev/captcha-dev$ grunt
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>> 3 files lint free.

Running "protractor:singlerun" (protractor) task
[19:08:51] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[19:08:51] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:08:52] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.117:55627/wd/hub
Started
........

8 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 19.148 seconds
[19:09:12] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[19:09:12] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[19:09:12] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

Done.
```

But when I try to perform it via TeamCity...
I've got *this*:

```
Step 1/1: Run captcha tests via Protractor (Command Line)
[18:25:21][Step 1/1] Starting: /var/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script2979762391918001494
[18:25:21][Step 1/1] in directory: /var/buildAgent/work/bc9e47ac95c1cdb2
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >> 3 files lint free.
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] 
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] Running "protractor:singlerun" (protractor) task
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] 
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] /var/buildAgent/work/bc9e47ac95c1cdb2/captcha-dev/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:25
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] const builder = require('./builder');
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] ^^^^^
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at require (module.js:380:17)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/buildAgent/work/bc9e47ac95c1cdb2/captcha-dev/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:8:17)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >> /var/buildAgent/work/bc9e47ac95c1cdb2/captcha-dev/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:25
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >> const builder = require('./builder');
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >> ^^^^^
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >> SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at require (module.js:380:17)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/buildAgent/work/bc9e47ac95c1cdb2/captcha-dev/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:8:17)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] >>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] Warning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 8  Use --force to continue.
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] 
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] Aborted due to warnings.
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 8
[18:25:22][Step 1/1] Step Run captcha tests via Protractor (Command Line) failed
```

Versions of Node.js, npm and Protractor on my computer and on the TeamCity agent are the same.

```
node v6.2.2
npm v3.9.5
protractor 4.0.0
```

*Gruntfile.js*:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    jshint: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'Client/Test_E2E/*.js'],
        options: {
            // options here to override JSHint defaults
            globals: {
                jQuery: true,
                console: true,
                module: true,
                document: true
            },
            loopfunc:true
        }
    },
    protractor: {
        options: {
            keepAlive: true,
            configFile: "Client/Test_E2E/conf.js"
        },
        singlerun: {},
        auto: {
            keepAlive: true,
            options: {
                args: {
                    directConnect: true
                    // seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar'
                }
            }
        }

    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'protractor:singlerun']);
};
```

*conf.js*:

```
exports.config = {
 allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

 specs: [
   'test.js'
 ],

 capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'chrome'
 },

 baseUrl: 'http://localhost:55555/',

 framework: 'jasmine',

 jasmineNodeOpts: {
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
 },

   onPrepare: function() {
       var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
       jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
           consolidateAll: true,
           savePath: 'testresults',
           filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
       }));
   }
};
```

Spend all day googling and searching but still dunno why locally all works and on TC not. Maybe it's because I'm using Grunt and TeamCity just week? : ) I dunno. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.
**EDIT**
forgot to tell TC version - TeamCity Professional 9.1.7
still dunno how to figure out this problem, already in despair :) trying to rewrite stuff from Protractor to Karma, but as I understand it's using only to unit tests, while I need E2E (imitate user clicking, filling forms etc)...

Comment: Very much similar symptoms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789889/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode.

Comment: @alecxe yeah, but his solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Looking for possibilities...Is it possible that you followed the directions from the other post but as yourself and not the user running TeamCity (so maybe cleared a different cache location)?

Comment: @dcbyers  solution in that post is to update nodejs. Like I mentioned in my post on my computer and on TC node is up to date