# Angular CLI Error

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

Installed angular CLI through the command below.

```
npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
```

It got installed with the following message:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2 
  ├─┬ css-loader@0.23.1
  │ └─┬ cssnano@3.7.4
  │   └─┬ autoprefixer@6.4.0
  │     └── caniuse-db@1.0.30000525 
  └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.0

npm WARN @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.2.2 requires a peer of typescript@^1.9.0-dev but none was installed.
npm WARN tsickle@0.1.6 requires a peer of typescript@^1.8.0 || ^1.9.0-dev but none was installed.
npm WARN tsickle@0.1.6 requires a peer of typescript@^1.8.0 || ^1.9.0-dev but none was installed.
```

Now whenever I try to use `ng new proj_name` command it shows following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:7
const resolve = require('resolve');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

What is the problem here?

**Update:**

Node Version : v0.10.35

Npm Version : 3.10.5

Comment: I think that your node version is very old. Try to update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` was introduced by `ES6` and `node` versions below 0.12 don't support it.
Try updating your `node` version

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode) link for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

The warning you got is "normal", I also got them and the cli works.

The solution seems related to your version of node (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36790307/1630604) or this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/959)).

Comment: Thanx It's the problem with my node version.