# Husky giving error SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: node.js, git, stylelint, husky, lint-staged

I am using [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) with [Lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) and [Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/)

```
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged",

  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.scss": ["stylelint --syntax scss"
    ]
  },
```

OS - Latest OSX

Node - `6.10.0`

NPM - `3.10.00`

I'm getting this error on `git commit`

```
> husky - npm run -s precommit

/Users/jitendravyas/app/node_modules/lint-staged/src/index.js:6
const path = require('path')
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jitendravyas/app/node_modules/lint-staged/index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)

> husky - pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
> husky - to debug, use 'npm run precommit'
```

Answer (score 6):

I was using node `7.10.0` and had the same problem. I found [an issue logged on it's repo](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/129) where [mmoutenot](https://github.com/mmoutenot) posted an interesting reply which got me thinking so I looked into it further and found the solution!

Husky assumes that everyone uses **nvm** to manage node versions and looks for it under [NVM_DIR](https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/master/src/index.js#L106)(**set to `$HOME/.nvm`**) or if installed with brew [BREW_NVM_DIR](https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/master/src/index.js#L113)(**set to `/usr/local/opt/nvm`**)

if either path exists than it loads the node version using [load_nvm](https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/master/src/index.js#L64-L69).

When I initially started working with Node I did use **nvm** but later on moved on to using [n](https://github.com/tj/n) and didn't realise that **.nvm** had not been cleaned up under the home directory so it was pointing to an older version of node(`0.12.7`) - which caused above mentioned error.

If you are still using nvm to manage node versions please ensure that you update to node version that supports ES6 features(`const` in this case).

If you are not using nvm than ensure that the **nvm** is not available on above mentioned paths. Husky ends up using the current version in that case (i.e. `6.10.0` in your case)

Alternatively you can try the solution that [mmoutenot](https://github.com/mmoutenot) mentioned on [husky issue](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/129)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to pass a glob of what files to lint for stylelint also:

```
"scripts": {
  "precommit": "lint-staged",

},
"lint-staged": {
  "*.scss": ["stylelint \"**/*.scss\" --syntax scss"
  ]
},
```