# Visual Studio Task Runner "SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode."

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Using Win10 Pro / VS2015 with a 'website' project (not asp.net, basic website)

When attempt to save/reload gulpfile.js I receive the error message (from Task Runner Explorer/output)

> SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

*In the present case it is choking on 'gulp-changed'*

I have looked through the answers and comments available:

- [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22603078/681009)
- [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36789889/681009)

  1. I have updated my version of node to the latest: 6.10.30
  2. I have cleaned the cache (npm cache clean -f)
  3. I have used 'which node' to determine that node is pointing to the installation of the latest install.
  4. "n" does not want to install on Windows (?)

---

[image: In my case the environment path, $(PATH) already include the global install of node but I needed to move it ahead of the $(DevEnvDir) paths so that it would get priority.]
In my case the environment path, $(PATH) already include the global install of node but I needed to move it ahead of the $(DevEnvDir) paths so that it would get priority.

*(added after correct answer provided, thanks @baao)*

Comment: What's the output for `node -v` ?

Comment: v6.10.3 (1 above)

Comment: I think here's your answer: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/178#issuecomment-218131138

Comment: Perfect...please make that an answer, I should like to give you proper credit.

Comment: @baao Thanks, but your answer is what put me onto the trail of the information I added in, only to show others how to implement what you suggested to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

VS seems to install (and then use) an old version of node, which is why the task runner is breaking the build.

Go to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools` and add the correct path to your node version (find the path with `which node`).

Credits to: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/178#issuecomment-218131138