# Visual Studio Task Runner Error with ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, gulp

I am running Visual Studio 2017 and use the Task Runner to run tasks in my `gulpfile`. I recently updated a gulp task to ES6 and now am getting this error:

`Failed to run "C:\Users\nz9rcn\Code\WebUI\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
C:\Users\nz9rcn\Code\WebUI\gulp-tasks\lesslint.js:5
let fail = false;
^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at task (C:\Users\nz9rcn\Code\WebUI\gulpfile.js:24:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nz9rcn\Code\WebUI\gulpfile.js:37:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)`

Can't find a place to adjust the settings causing this error (strict mode). Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure Visual Studio supports ES6 out of the box? By the error it looks like it doesn't recognize ES6 syntax - maybe you need a tool like Babel to transpire first? Not sure how that would be accomplished with this task runner though.

Comment: @ryandrewjohnson according to this document, ES6 is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017

Comment: [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is a language feature that's enabled within code. 
Include `"use strict";` either as the 1st line of the file or 1st line of the function's body that's using `let`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I believe the issue is that Visual Studio is choosing to run code in 'use strict' mode, as I do not have the statement in my code, and therefore needs to be turned off in VS. I can't remove it from my code because it is not there.

Comment: @BenRondeau It should be the other way. To use `let`, you'll have to use strict mode. Since you haven't opted into the mode, the declaration isn't permitted. (Though, that was a temporary restriction in Google's V8. The version in Node 8 should allow `let` both with and without strict mode.)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Problem solved below. Visual Studio was targeting an old version of Node to run ES6

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Issue solved by un-checking the box for the Node.js binary used by Task Runner:

[image]

In the menu, go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Projects and Solutions` > `Web Package Management` > `External Web Tools` and DESELECT the option for `$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External`

The version installed in that directory doesn't support `ES6` apparently.

References for solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120850/visual-studio-task-runner-syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode) and [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/178#issuecomment-218131138).

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much for this !

Comment: I wish i could upvote this more than once. Thank you.