# SyntaxError when trying to do anything in npm

Tags: npm

I came back to a Win10 PC I haven't used in a while. First thing, I tried to update [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) with

```
> npm i npm -g
```

I got back this:

```
added 290 packages, removed 250 packages and updated 37 packages in 38.815s
   ╭─────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                     │
   │   Update available 5.0.0 → 6.4.1    │
   │     Run npm i -g npm to update      │
   │                                     │
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Then, I tried to run `npm i -g npm` and got:

```
     let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Now when I try to do anything, I get that same error. In case you were wondering I was trying to update from npm `5.0.0` to `6.4.1`.

---

### *Things I've tried*

I Googled this error and found the following:

- [Update Node](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/264)

  - Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407/1152809) I first tried to clear npm's cache with `npm cache clean -f`, but got the same `SyntaxError`.
  - The same instructions also say to do some stuff with nvm, which I don't have, so I tried to install it with `npm i nvm -g`, but same error.
- [use strict](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-do-i-keep-getting-this-error), even though I know this is for a program using node. I wanted to be sure I tried everything before posting a question.

  - `'"use strict"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.`
- [Fresh npm install of webpack.js is throwing Block-scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244803/fresh-npm-install-of-webpack-js-is-throwing-block-scope-error) but this didn't seem to apply to me because I'm not using Visual Studio, and I haven't done anything with babel or webpack or es6. I'm just trying to update npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any answers so I decided to completely uninstall node and npm using these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/1152809

Then I reinstalled node and everything works as expected.