# changing the node version in visual studio code for windows 10

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have run into an odd issue. I am using Visual Studio Code v 1.16 on Windows 10, and I have installed node v6.11.3 to run on my local machine. When I check the version number under the Terminal in VS code. It returns 0.12.2, and I cannot access the newer version of node. Which is causing issues with development.

Can someone please tell me how to change the version of Node.js in VS code?

Edit 1: I have attempted the solution found here [Visual Studio Task Runner "SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120850/visual-studio-task-runner-syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

I was not able to resolve the issue this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Task Runner "SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120850/visual-studio-task-runner-syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

Comment: The question and my answer to the original question explains how to select the version in vs

Comment: @baao Please note that the question is related to Visual Studio Code. Not Visual studio community. The issue is arising from a versioning problem in Code, and not community.

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Comment: @baao I am attempting the solution now, and I need to restart. I will check and see if that resolved my issue, but I am going through VS 2015 to do so. Code does not have the option for External Web Tools

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154548/discussion-between-joshua-and-baao).