# node not running , websocket error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting an error when I try to run my node.I have installed ws and websocket, but seems that none is working

[image: Image of error]

Comment: What version of Node.js are you running?

Comment: It says "Use of const in strict mode". There's your problem. Update node. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789889/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode

Comment: I'm currently running v0.12.18

Comment: I've already update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what is happening is that you are executing your script with an older version of node (more specifically V8) that had restrictions on how/where some ES6 features could be used. Upgrading node (*at least* to v4.0.0) should fix the problem.

Comment: isnt the v0.12.18 the last version?

Comment: @PedroGaspar Nope. The latest long term supported NodeJS version is 6. See: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Jesus , this  , can you help me giving command lines as i'm using vps , also do you recommend version 6 or 8 .

Comment: Node v8.x won't become an LTS branch until October. Node v6.x is currently the newest LTS branch. It's up to you to choose because there are multiple factors that come into play when deciding what branch to go with.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace 'const' by 'var'. Strict mode forces you to declare your variables explicitely.

Comment: Can you be more detailed? Change const by var in js file?

Comment: Exactly, change "const myVar = require(...)" by "var myVar = require(...)". As mscdex said, the "const myVar = " syntax is not supported by your version. Anyway, using const on an object reference only makes the reference const, not the object itself that can still be modified later on.