# How do I list Node.js version and path currently being used in npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, ubuntu

I'm currently running into the same error as this Stackoverflow question had: [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789889/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode), although I'm getting it while trying to [install Flux](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc).

I've already updated my system's Node.js version with the commands shown in the linked Stackoverflow question.

```
npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

When I run `node --version` I get the correct version, `v8.2.1`. However, when I install modules via npm, I still get warnings such as

```
npm WARN engine har-schema@1.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
```

...which suggests that npm is still using an old version of Node.

Is there a way that I can find the version of Node seen by npm, and can I determine the directory where it is installed to?

Comment: What does `which npm` print?

Comment: check that `nodejs --version` also returns the correct version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried `npm info` which isn't a thing evidently, because I got all errors. But the first line was my OS version, second was PATH to node.exe and PATH to npm-cli.js, third was node version, fourth was npm version. Then invalid package.json, etc, etc
I'm sure there's a right way, but I think it showed me everything you are hoping to see...
Forgive me for suggesting bad answer. Maybe just check your npm-debug.log
Perhaps you can find answers to your questions there.

** EDIT 
I found something in `npm help`

try `npm config list`

Comment: `npm config list` gave me the `node bin location`, and also led me to `npm config ls -l` which contained a `node-version` string. As it turns out, npm is using an absolute path to /usr/bin/nodejs. The latest version of node is installed to /usr/local/bin/node with a symlink to /usr/local/bin/nodejs, but npm seems happy to ignore my $PATH variable entirely. Now I just need to find a way to point npm to the proper directory and I'm set.