# Error with node site.js

Tags: node.js

I have problem with log4js.

Problem is that when i ran node.sj error pops up:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'log4js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bot/site.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

So i instaled log4js with:

npm install log4js

And now the real error is here:

```
/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/log4js.js:25
const debug = require('debug')('log4js:main');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bot/site.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Maybe i have broken bot. But bot should be OK.

I had this error in past but i fixed it and do not know how. (about 2years ago?) and error was in bot folder i think.

i have Debian 7 installed on server
Thx for response.

Comment: Find the link below. Hope it helps you! [clickhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36790307/7027245)

Comment: Thy it solved my error but another error pops up:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of node.js are you running?

`node --version`

First of all try to install your application packages with `npm install log4j --save` (to save it in your package.json).

It seems that you are using an old version of node.js!

Using this site you can see when the keyword `const` was introduced without requiring the `strict` keyword!

http://node.green/#ES2015-bindings-const

To fix the error just need to update your node.js to the latest stable version.

Another solutions: (The previous one is my favourite).

You can set a single specific file to be strict by writing `'use strict'` on top of your file.

Or you can force to run your whole application to strict by using `node --use_strict index.js` (I wont recommend this one)