# Getting use of const in strict mode error in Actions on Google app after updating Node.js packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, strict

I have a Node.JS (version 8.6) based Google Home app that uses the Actions on Google Javascript client library.  It has built and ran fine for several days now.  I added a few packages to the project and all of a sudden I start getting the following fatal error in the Actions on Google Javascript client library, despite the fact the code in that library has not been touched:

```
/**
 * The Actions on Google client library.
 * https://developers.google.com/actions/
 */

'use strict';

const AssistantApp = require('./assistant-app');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/roschler/Documents/GitHub/YourMD/google-assistant/morse-integration/routes/fulfillment.js:16:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I never got this error before.  Below is my *package.json* file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.3.17",
    "actions-on-google": "^1.4.0",
    "archiver": "^1.3.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "config": "^1.21.0",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "glob": "~7.0.3",
    "http-status-codes": "~1.0.6",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jsonfile": "~2.2.3",
    "marked": "^0.3.5",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "pg": "^6.1.4",
    "redis": "^2.6.1",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "scribe-js": "~2.0.4",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "showdown": "^1.7.1",
    "simple-spinner": "0.0.5",
    "ssl-root-cas": "~1.2.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?  I tried updating my Node.JS version as per the accepted answer the Stack Overflow post below regarding a similar error, but it did not help:

[SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789889/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

I still get the error.

**UPDATE**:  I forgot that I also upgraded from Node 7.2 to 8.6.  I believe now that's what is causing my issues.  I'm in the process of doing a full purge of Node.js and then installing nvm so I can test versions.

Comment: What version of Node?

Comment: What are the lines just before the require()?

Comment: @Mark_M Version 8.6.

Comment: @Prisoner - I just added those to my post.  Pretty much just 'use strict' and some comments before that.  As I said, I haven't touched the code in that file.

Comment: All signs point to the fact that you aren't actually getting node v8.6 when you run your app and have some older version that is causing this.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think it's the opposite.  All my troubles started when I upgraded from 7.2 to 8.6.  I'm going to do a complete purge and install nvm and then go back to an older version to see what happens.

Comment: I rather doubt that 8.x broke the use of `const`.  Perhaps something went wrong with your upgrade process though.  Probably also worth ruling out some other cause by creating a simple test file with nothing else in it, but this issue.

Comment: For Actions on Google you have to use the LTS version of nodejs - which is 6.x

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer Thanks. I ended up reverting to 6.11.1 since that is what Firebase uses and you're right, the problem went away when I did that.

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer please be more specific. Actions on Google is a platform that doesn't have any specific platform requirements. If you mean the AoG Node package has an Engine requirement please link to where that is specified.

Comment: @abraham Actually I got confused and mixed up Cloud Functions and it's implications for this lib. Cloud Functions (both variants) require node with LTS. The actions-on-google lib most likely not. At least all my tests run fine with the newest node version as well with the LTS version. When I got the same error it was on Cloud Functions.