# node.js const R = require('ramda'); - SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, vps

I have nodejs on Linux so when i start app.js it gives me this error.

> [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789889/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode) - that don't help

P.S - yes i'm install ramda

```
const R = require('ramda'); SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/app.js:4:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: `Updating nodejs solved the issue:` thats it. Ifit is definetly not please tell us what node version you are using.

Comment: yes, you're right version - 0.10.0 but now i'n update to 8.10.0. THANKS!

Comment: Glad to help :) the next time please read the answers carefully...