# dockerfile npm start with harmony

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Due to a new npm package I installed I recently started to receive SyntaxErrors concerning the use of the keyword '**const**'.

After some research, I came across [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode) on StackOverflow, saying that ECMAScript2015 isn't enabled by default on the older Node.js

As I'm using **Docker** to host my web application, I'm wondering how to include **harmony-tag** into the **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM centos:centos6

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y nodejs npm

COPY package.json /ProjectName/package.json

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /ProjectName

RUN npm install --production

COPY . /ProjectName

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Or do you consider another solution?

Thanks

Comment: The same commands you would use on any Linux system, inside your RUN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the flag in your package.json start script command. But i would recommend using the official node container as a base and use at least the lts (currently 4.6) version. Older node versions are pretty outdated and with docker it should be pretty easy to update.

Official node image:

https://hub.docker.com/_/node/