# angular-cli produces syntax error when ran

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I am trying to use the angular-cli project however I get this error when I run

```
$ ng new scotchy-scotch
C:\Users\....\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v0.12.10\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng:7
const resolve = require('resolve');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the angular-cli [github page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites):

> Prerequisites:
>
> Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies
> that require Node 4 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.

The `const` are part of ES6(ECMAscript 2015) which is not enabled by default in nodejs v0.12(which one you use). [Related stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)