# How can I make this npm project works?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I'm trying to make working a tool that I found on Github and I'm not able to get in touch with the creator of this.

I've this output:

```
const express = require('express'),
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.29\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.9.5\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! PROJECT-NAME@0.0.0 start: `node ./app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
```

How can I do (I'm using windows)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

Comment: No, it's a different situation

Comment: Have you tried updating the version of node you're using? There's also many different questions with this same problem. Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Try the top answer on the question that is linked ? Does it not work ? You could remove all occurences of `'use strict'` by hand of course

Comment: I tried to remove 'use strict' but there are a lot of other issues. I think that the problem is about the version of npm and node.js, but I don't know how to update them on windows server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable some of the ECMAScript 2015 features (including `const`) in Node.js 0.10 start your node program with a harmony flag, otherwise you will get a syntax error. For example:

```
node --harmony app.js
```

Comment: Can you tell me more? How can I do?

Comment: @KingFuzz the same way you start `node ./app.js`. Just add the "--harmony" flag there.

Comment: Mhhh.. in the app.js file?

Comment: @KingFuzz No, in the command line. How do you launch the project, exactly?

Comment: "npm install" and then "npm install"

Comment: Thanks! I've done this, but now I have this problem: app.get('/:code/:user/:pass', (req, res) => {
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Comment: How can I do? Please can you help me?

Comment: Help with what? Updating node.js?

Comment: Yes, on windows server

Comment: The same way you've already done it. Uninstall node.js, download the newer version from the nodejs.org website (but take the **Current** one, not **LTS** version), and install it again.