# I cannot install npm package error strict mode

Tags: node.js, npm

When I install **sudo npm i sharp -g**

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/sharp/binding.js:3
const fs = require('fs');
^^^^^ 

SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

When I try install some packages with ES6 syntax

After upadate nodejs and npm my versions is

```
node -v  -----> v6.9.4
npm -v   -----> 4.1.2
node-gyp -v ----> v3.4.0
```

I tried to use this command

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

But it does not work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Node and reinstalled from the official site. It appears I had an old version of node in there causing issues. Installs worked just fine after that.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/