# AspNetCore + Angular 2: WebpackDevMiddleware Error with new project

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, angular2-template

I'm creating a new project with this tutorial:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

Next some resolved issues, I have now a complete project with all dependencies installed but when I launch the project with IIS, I have this error .

```
    L'exception System.AggregateException s'est produite
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=<Impossible d'évaluer la source de l'exception>
  Arborescence des appels de procédure :
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebpackDevMiddleware.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder, WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions options)
   at Test.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\VS2017\Project\Test\Startup.cs:line 44

Exception interne 1 :
Exception : Call to Node module failed with error: Webpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: C:\VS2017\Project\Test\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:7
const Compiler = require("./Compiler");
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\VS2017\Project\Test\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
Current directory is: C:\VS2017\Project\Test
```

I don't know which step I failed so if someone already did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `aspnet-webpack` node package requires a newer version of `node`.

> The const and let are part of ECMAScript 2015 (a.k.a. ES6 and Harmony), and was not enabled by default in Node.js 0.10 or 0.12. Since Node.js 4.x, “All shipping [ES2015] features, which V8 considers stable, are turned on by default on Node.js and do NOT require any kind of runtime flag.”.
>
> So by upgrading to Node.js 4.x or newer the error should disappear.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151062/5082427

**Update**

You can check the installed version of node by executing `node -v` in the command-line. If this command outputs an older version than the one you have installed, check the `PATH` environment variable to ensure you don't have multiple node installations.

Comment: Im using Node 6

Comment: @Elykx are you sure? Could you type "node -v" in the command-line and comment the results?

Comment: Thats what i get
node -v
v0.12.2

Comment: So, you're not using Node 6. You're using Node 0.12.2.

Comment: I installed this version https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.2/node-v6.10.2-x64.msi    
I don't know if i have to update something else

Comment: That's peculiar, it seems you have multiple versions of node installed then. Try checking your PATH environment variable and see if there are multiple paths to a node installation in there.

Comment: Ah i had an other version installed on program files (x86), i removed it and its working now. Thanks for your time.