# Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack' when using 'Bootstrap4 & popper.js' in .Net Core 2.0 & knockout spa template

Tags: c#, webpack, knockout.js, asp.net-core-2.0, popper.js

I created my .NetCore 2.0 & knockout project using command line. I successfully created and install npm packages.project run successfully. Then I update the version of Bootstrap from 3.3.7 to 4.1.3 and install
popper.js using npm and  trying to run my project, my project spits out this error

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Webpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\knockout1\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
Current directory is: C:\Users\knockout1
)'
```

i updated my Webpack packages but no avail.Please help....

Comment: This thread should be helpful:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911802/cannot-find-module-aspnet-webpack-when-using-dotnet-publish-in-net-core-2-0)

Comment: I checked that link and follow his steps. but error didn't remove