# oidc-debugger showing error Error: Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack'

Tags: openid-connect

I am new to the oidc-debugger and I installed oidc-debugger on RHEL 8.9. But while executing the dotnet run I am getting "Error: Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack'". I installed the below pre-requisites,
dotnet-sdk-2.1
webpack-dev-server
my node version is v16.20.2
Someone please help us to understand how to resolve it.

I have installed the pre-requisites and tried to execute the dotnet run
I am expecting to execute the dotnet run without any errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack' when using 'dotnet publish' in .Net Core 2.0 & Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911802/cannot-find-module-aspnet-webpack-when-using-dotnet-publish-in-net-core-2-0)

Comment: No, it's not give me solution for my issue