# Angular code in Codeship then Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I would like to post a basik Angular code to Codeship then heroku. But I have a problem what i can't solve. I got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grM4a.png).
I searched, i found a that node version is too old, but my node version in my computer is the newest 6.11.0, npm 3.10.10.

```
    {
  "name": "anonymous",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "http-server dist -p $PORT",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --single-run",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "node-wget": "^0.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "wget": "0.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

I don't know where to set node version in an angular project.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this error because the version of Node used by your Codeship build server is too old.
As per your [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grM4a.png) it is currently using version `v0.10.48`.

You need to update the Node Version as part of the CodeShip deployment.

Assuming you are using a custom script, you need the following line to it.

```
#Update node to version 6.11.0
nvm install 6.11.0
```

Note that you need Node 4.1 or later for the Angular CLI.