# gitbook-cli install error, gitbook-cli -v cannot be use

Tags: node.js, npm, gitbook

after i install the nodejs and npm , gitbook-cli ,there is an error.like this:

```
[root@vagrant-centos65 vagrant]# gitbook -v

/usr/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:3
const assign = require('./util/assign')
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/lib/config.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[root@vagrant-centos65 vagrant]# npm -v
1.3.6
[root@vagrant-centos65 vagrant]# node -v
v0.10.48
```

my nodejs version and npm are v0.10.48 ,1.3.6 ,what should i do ,please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151062/5156280) answer explain, `const` support is not enabled by default in *node.js* version 0.10 and require `--harmony` flag if you want to use it.

As this version of *fs-extra* package use `const` keyword in his index.js file, you got this error.

You can have a look at [this](http://node.green/#ES2015-bindings-const-basic-support--strict-mode-) compatibility table for a summary for `const` and `let` support by version.

Just upgrade your *node.js* version to solve this issue.

Also, I don't think it is a good idea to launch *gitbook* as root user.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @ TGrif , i upgrade my nodejs ,and its worked.

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.0.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

[How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js/19584407#19584407)