# Why dependencies library version is different between package.json and npm info

Tags: json, node.js, sparkpost

I found following error when I'm rendering my nodejs project

> {"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException SyntaxError: Use of
>   const in strict mode.\n at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)\n at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)\n at Module.load
>   (module.js:356:32)\n at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)\n at
>   Module.require (module.js:364:17)\n at require (module.js:380:17)\n at
>   Object.
>   (/var/www/myproject/dist/node_modules/sparkpost/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/index.js:5:33)\n
>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)\n at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)\n at Module.load
>   (module.js:356:32)\n at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)\n at
>   Module.require (module.js:364:17)\n at require (module.js:380:17)\n at
>   Object.
>   (/var/www/myproject/dist/node_modules/sparkpost/node_modules/request/request.js:9:12)\n
>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)\n at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:474:10)","timestamp":"2017-09-25T02:45:43.418Z"}

That's why I check sparkpost version inside my package.json file and found `"sparkpost": "^1.3.7",` but when I checked with `npm info sparkpost version`, it goes `2.1.2`

Can something help me any suggestion that how can I check actual version of sparkpost and how can I fix that error message, thanks.

Comment: It looks like `sparkpost` does not in fact support very old Node.js versions. Upgrading to at least Node 4.x might be your best solution. I opened [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost/issues/224) on this too.

Comment: @EwanDennis can you please tell me how to use `Old Node.js needs --harmony to enable const.`

Comment: I doubt continuing with Node.js 0.10 will resolve this problem. I strongly recommend you upgrade to at least Node.js v4. The current versions are always linked at [https://nodejs.org/en/](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Answer (score 2):

`npm info <package_name>` outputs the registry info for the latest version of `<package_name>` (unless you specify a version). That is, it's not going to describe your local package. `npm help info` explains all the gory details.

Instead, you can use `npm list sparkpost` to determine the version of sparkpost you have locally. Or, you can always manually inspect the locally installed version by examining the dependency's package.json with something like `cat node_modules/sparkpost/package.json | grep version`.

As for the actual error: you need to provide more context. You could get this if you're running a version of node < 4.0.0 without the `--harmony` flag. Depending on your application's requirements, you could update node or add the harmony flag to try resolving the error. Have a look at: [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)