# Rails+webpacker on safari / SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, safari, ecmascript-6, webpacker

Currently using a default  rails app install with webpacker and react, I'm stuck with the following error `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'.  Const declarations are not supported in strict mode`

I might be possible to extend this easily I guess, just have no clue about how to do it. I tried to use some webpack config I do have in other working nodejs environments, with no success.

Thx a lot for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

Comment: @hoffm You're saying it should work out of the box on safari with the default rails/webpacker ?