# node server.js throws error

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

running node server.js just throws error like this.
anyone knows why ??

```
/xxxxxx/server/node_modules/connect/node_modules/mime/index.js:3
const Mime = require('./Mime');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/xxxxxx/server/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:21:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151062/1790644), try launching with the `--harmony` flag. i.e. `node --harmony myApp.js` Or download and install the latest stable version of node.

Comment: Is it possible you are running an ancient node.js version? Example for others with this issue: https://github.com/hapijs/boom/issues/164 -- By the way, if you google whatever error message you have you often find the solution right away. Works in this case too, google for *"SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode."* to check out how to get an immediate answer without having to ask on SO.

Comment: hi @MattClark using --harmony resulted in class Mime {
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/xxxxxx/server/node_modules/connect/node_modules/mime/index.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)