# Ember Installation Issue: SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: node.js, windows, ember.js, installation

When trying to install Ember.js on Windows (and possibly other systems), after running the following commands:

```
npm install -g npm
npm install -g ember-cli
npm install -g bower
```

No errors are raised, how the command `ember -v` outputs the following:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\cli\index.js:3
const willInterruptProcess = require('../utilities/will-interrupt-process');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at C:\Users\Shayn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember:26:11
    at C:\Users\Shayn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:50:13
    at processDirs (C:\Users\Shayn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:182:39)
```

This suggests an issue with my Ember installation, how can I address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is suggested in a few other answers, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35218558/7195043), however this exact solution will not work on Windows.

Instead, the best solution is to get the [latest version of Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed via an installer.

To verify after installation try the following:

```
node --version
```

Which should output something like:

```
v8.9.1
```

Previously this command would have given a lower version number. In my case it was similar to `v0.12`.