# Use of const in strict mode (Angular 2)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

My node version is v9.3.0 and the npm version is 5.5.1.
I am trying to create and run a sample project using:

```
ng new test;
ng serve -o;
```

The the angular cli compiles the program successfully but my browser page is blank and the console log results in:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

Firstly, how can i avod this error ?
How does the strict mode get enabled in this case ?

EDIT:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which browser? What's your tsconfig look like, what is the compile target?

Comment: @Zlakto My browser is chrome and compile target is es5. Should I edit my question with the tsconfig file or look for any specific options ?

Comment: @Zlakto edited my question with the tsconfig file.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603078/syntaxerror-use-of-const-in-strict-mode it might help you

Comment: @atishshimpi This is where I referred to initially but was of no use. I am using the latest version of node.js

Comment: @atishshimpi I think it is an issue with angular on my machine not node.js.

Comment: Try changing npm version to 6.9.0 or latest

Comment: @atishshimpi  Any cmd command to update it.

Comment: Try npm update [-g] [<pkg>...]  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue resolved in below GitHub discussion 
[Link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2100)

Below is how the issue was handled, trying this may help you resolve the issue.

If you have a working version prior to update go to that installation and use:

```
npm shrinkwrap 
or npm shrinkwrap --dev
```

then a new file will be created

npm-shrinkwrap.json

Check that file and make sure dependencies are created. Normally this file has all the existing dependencies. Put that file in the folder which you run npm install inside. NPM will use the old versions and should work.

As an alternative you can remove all unrelated dependencies and keep only node-sass with request dependency.

```
        "node-sass": {
        "version": "2.1.1",
        "from": "node-sass@>=2.0.1 <3.0.0",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass/-/node-sass-2.1.1.tgz",
        "dependencies": {
          "request": {
            "version": "2.79.0",
            "from": "request@>=2.53.0 <3.0.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.79.0.tgz",
          },
        }
      },
```