# In browser, assign a new value to "window" object doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, browser

In browser, I tried to evaluate the following snippet:

```
window = 1; console.log(window)
```

The value printed in console is still the original window object instead of number `1`.

Does anyone have ideas about why `window` object can't be re-assigned? Is this a feature of Javascript language? Can I make my own object not writable like window object too?

Comment: Because it's by definition not writable.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Is this done in language-level? or in environment-level? Can I make my own object not writable like `window` object too?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` allows you to create objects that cannot be overridden. The `window` object is made in a similar fashion, by the engine that runs your code.

Comment: Yes you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-window):

> The `window`, `frames`, and `self` IDL attributes must all return the `Window` object's browsing context's `WindowProxy` object.

The *"must"* here implying that no matter what you do, every request to `window` will result in the WindowProxy object.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be overwritten because it is defined as being non-writable.

That is a feature of JS (although the `window` object is probably implemented at a lower level).

```js
var example = {};
Object.defineProperty(example, "foo", {
  value: "Hello",
  writable: false
});

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(example.foo));
example.foo = "World";
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(example.foo));
```

Comment: This is not a feature of JS but of the DOM API.

Comment: @bfontaine — The DOM API defines the requirement that it be read only. The JavaScript language implements that requirement.