# Prevent Overriding Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I'm using a Modular Pattern in JavaScript. I wonder if we can prevent the public modules to be overridden.
For example, in the code below **function1, function2, function3 and function4** can be accessed outside but I don't want to override. If these functions are overridden then I want the compiler to generate an error message

```
"use strict";

var $ = (function(){
return{
      function1 : function(){
          alert("this is Function1");
      },
      function2 : function(){
          alert("this is Function2");
      },
      function3 : function(){
          alert("this is Function3");
      },
      function4 : function(){
          alert("this is Function4");
      }
    };
}());


$.function1(); //will alert - this is Function1
$.function2(); //will alert - this is Function2

/* 
  I don't want to do this, If I do, then I want the compiler to generate an   
  error message
*/
$.function3=function(){
    alert('function 3 is overridden');

};
$.function3(); //will alert - function 3 is overridden
```

Comment: For more in-depth discussion on this issue on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Object.freeze(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to set the entire returned object to be immutable. Additionally, note that you can use `const` instead of `var` to avoid the object being reassigned.

```js
'use strict';

const $ = (function() {
  return Object.freeze({
    function1: function() {
      alert('this is Function1');
    },
    function2: function() {
      alert('this is Function2');
    },
    function3: function() {
      alert('this is Function3');
    },
    function4: function() {
      alert('this is Function4');
    }
  });
})();


$.function1(); //will alert - this is Function1
$.function2(); //will alert - this is Function2

// This will now error
$.function3 = function() {
  alert('function 3 is overridden');
};
$.function3(); // will not run
```

Comment: Awesome & Thanks ! This is what I need.

Comment: There is still one problem. When I try to write the code like this, it will still override the function (by using Anonymous function). When I run it it will display the alert and then only it will give the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property". And later when I try to call the function, it will not work at all because of the anonymous overridden function.                                                                                $.function3=(function(){
    alert('function 3 is overridden');
}());

Comment: @greencheese Your example is a self-invoking function/IIFE. The override doesn't actually succeed but the function does get run before the error happens. See if this helps with understanding: https://jsfiddle.net/0oku2tah/1/

Comment: @greencheese If you want to catch this kind of error at compile-time, you'll need to run a third-party type checker during your development process. That will *not* prevent people who use your code from modifying it though.

Answer (score 8):

Using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) you can declare the property as read-only.

```js
// Make sure an error is thrown when attempting to overwrite it
// Without strict-mode, re-assigning will fail silently
'use strict';

var API = {};
Object.defineProperty(API, 'function1', {
  writable: false,
  value: function() {
    console.log('Called function1');
  }
});

API.function1();
API.function1 = null;
```

Comment: There is a typo， writable,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be prevented by using the Object.defineProperty method. Just set the *writable* and *configurable* attribute to false. You can find more info about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

In your case, it should look like this:

```
var $ = (function(){

var newObject = {};

Object.defineProperty (newObject, "function1", {value: function() {  alert("this is Function1");}, writable:false, configurable:false});

// etc.

return object;
}());
```

Please note that setting the *writable* and *configurable* attributes to *false* just keeps the *function1* property from overwriting. However, since every function in the JavaScript is a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object, that Function object is not protected by using *writable:false*. So, for instance, the prototype of the *function1* can still be changed.

If you want to completely save your functions from modifying in any way, you should use the Object.freeze method. Please read [this](http://arqex.com/967/javascript-properties-enumerable-writable-configurable) very useful article.

Comment: This is the compatibility table for the Object.freeze method: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Object.freeze and this is the table for the Objact.defineProperty: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Object.defineProperty. Those tables are identical.

Answer (score 0):

There are serveral ways to do that. If you want to handle the message when overriding, you can use [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set):

```js
var $ = (function(){
  var obj = {
      function1 : function(){
          alert("this is Function1");
      },
      function2 : function(){
          alert("this is Function2");
      },
      get function3() {
         alert("this is Function3");
      },
      set function3(value) {
         console.warn('You cannot override this function');
      },
      function4 : function(){
          alert("this is Function4");
      }
  };
  
  return obj
}());

// throw warning
$.function3 = 'foo';
```

Since you're using IIFE, you can define the source outside the property content and refer it.

Example with ES6 syntax:

```js
let $ = (function () {
  let func3 = function () {
    alert('this is Function3');
  };

  class $ {
    static set function3(value) {
      return func3;
    }
    static get function3() {
      return func3;
    }
  }
  
  return $;
}());

$.function3 = 'foo';
$.function3();
```