# Is it possible to create a JavaScript object to not be editable?

Tags: javascript

For example, say I have his function :

```
var person = (function(){
    var age = "will"

    function shoutAge(){
        alert(age)
    }

    return {
        shoutAge
    }
})()
```

After this is created I can do :

```
person.age = 45;
```

Granted, this is not the age inside the person scope, but this could cause confusion.

I changed it to use `const` :

```
const person = (function(){
    var age = "will"

    function shoutAge(){
        alert(age)
    }

    return {
        shoutAge
    }
})()
```

But I can still add custom properties.

*I misunderstood what const was for, you can't reassign the variable, but you can add properties to it fine.*

But is there a way to make it un-editable or is that something that shouldn't be done for some reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Read-Only Properties be Implemented in Pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366047/can-read-only-properties-be-implemented-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didnt realise a similar question was already asked. I feel the provided answer here seems to solve it better than the one in the link you sent, so perhaps the answer should be passed to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use `Object.freeze` on the object before returning it, [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

> prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed, it also prevents the prototype from being changed.

```js
'use strict';
var person = (function() {
  var age = "will"

  function shoutAge() {
    console.log(age)
  }

  return Object.freeze({
    shoutAge
  })
})();
person.shoutAge();
person.foo = 'foo';
```